# LibGDX, Box2D , Destroy body into parts

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am developing a game using libGDX game engine and box2d physics engine. There are asteroids in my game, I want to destroy their bodies randomly and fill with texture. How can I do it?

Comment: Are the asteroids made up multiple bodies? What do you mean by 'fill with texture'? Including a sketch would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Emanuele Feronato did a tutorial on this some time ago, you can use it as a base:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/03/05/breaking-objects-with-box2d-the-realistic-way/

To sum it up:

- Listen to collisions between your breakable body and the bodies that can break it;
- When collision happens, get the velocity of the body that can break the other and raycast it further;
- Use that raycast to cut the polygon of the breakable body in two;

Comment: The raycast usage looks excessive in the code here - it does the same thing anyway in a loop over the vertices to find a part of the broken body to which the vertices belongs.

Comment: @ei-grad That's true. This code could, and should be improved if intended to be used under production environments.